# How do I fix a leak at a decommissioned saddle-valve?

Tags: plumbing, leak, saddle-valve

Water is dripping, about a drop every other second, out of the end of this thing.

1. what is it?
2. why is it dripping?
3. can I fix it myself?

[image: leaky pipe fixture]

Comment: As **The Evil Greebo** said, *"Try tightening the valve, but carefully - don't over tighten. If that fails, your next best option is to cap it off. get a 1/4" brass cap from your local hardware/plumbing store"*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper name for it is a self piercing saddle valve. The valves are bad for many reasons, including the fact that they often clog and no longer allow water through the line, and they leak.

[image: self piercing saddle valve]

If you need a valve there to supply something like an ice maker or humidifier, then I'd cut the pipe, add a T, and put a proper quarter turn valve on the line.

To remove it, I'd just cut the pipe right on the piercing and install a copper coupling between the two cut pipes. The steps include: shutoff the water, remove the saddle valve (unscrew the two sides), cut the pipe, clean it, apply flux to the pipe and a copper coupling, fit them together, and solder the joint by heating with a blow torch and working solder into the joint from the opposite side. A skilled plumber should have the entire job done in under 30 minutes including setup and cleanup. For the DIY'er, you'll need the following tools and parts:

- Copper pipe cutter

[image: tubing cutter]

- Fitting brush

[image: Fitting brush]

- Flux and solder

[image: Flux and solder]

- Blow torch

[image: Blow torch]

- Copper coupling

[image: copper coupling]

<sub>Note, no affiliation or specific recommendation with any of the above brands, these are only sample images.</sub>

Comment: To install a coupling, depending on the existing pipe configuration, one may need a repair coupling that does not have a stop at the center. (the little dimple in the above image) The stop makes it difficult to slide the fitting back and forth in order to position it for the repair.

Comment: you can replace the fitting brush with some sandpaper (like that in the image of the flux and solder)

Comment: do you want a debur tool as well here?

Comment: I do not believe that fitting brush will work in this situation--look how much stuff is around it.  You either need one of the smaller fitting brushes (but they're tiring to turn!!) or emery cloth (which is no fun, either.)  Also, note that it's wood behind it.  A novice certainly needs some sort of flame shield.

Comment: @LorenPechtel good point on the emery cloth or smaller fitting brush. I'm a fan of flame shields too, but don't think it's needed in this situation, that looks like a joist, so well over 6" to the subfloor above.

Comment: @BMitch The person asking the question is a total novice and the wood is above the pipe.  Flame shield.

Answer (score 7):

It is saddle valve.  Generally they're used to supply ice makers.

[image]

It is dripping because the valve is either not closed completely, or because the valve has developed a leak.

Try tightening the valve, but carefully - don't over tighten.  If that fails, your next best option is to cap it off.  get a 1/4" brass cap from your local hardware/plumbing store:

[image]

Also get teflon tape:

[image]

Now, shut off the house water supply.  Remove the nut holding the tubing onto the valve.  Wrap two wraps of tape around the threads on the valve in the direction of threads.  Now screw on the cap and tighten until snug.  Turn on house water, and open the saddle valve and check for leaks.  Then close the saddle valve again.

Comment: Eek, a vampire tap!

Comment: So this option is "leave it on there, but just cap off the exit" is that right? Where do you put that cap?

Comment: Like I said - remove the tubing and cap it off.  It's an easier solution that cutting out a section of the pipe, although it only works if it's the tubing that's leaking.

Answer (score 6):

Cut the valve out and get a sharkbite slip-fitting.  Saddle valves eventually leak at the rubber-pipe intersection. Doing it this way doesn't require you to completely drain the line -- a skilled plumber can do a copper sweat job in 30 minutes, but you can do this in 5 minutes with a hacksaw, though a tubing cutter is preferred.

http://www.sharkbite.com/how-to/sharkbite-slip-coupling-copper-or-cpvc-repair/

Answer (score 2):

That is a tap (called a "saddle valve") for something like an ice maker or humidifier. It works by piercing a small hole in the larger copper pipe.

Turning the valve all the way clockwise should close it and stop the drip.

Ideally remove the old, no longer used valve and repair the hole. I do not know how to do that properly, so I yield to a plumbing expert.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "all the way" do you mean, _by hand_? Do I risk damaging the pipe or the valve if I go at it with a pair of pliers?

Comment: Do not use pliers on a valve like this.  If you can't shut it off completely using hand pressure alone, all you'll do is damage it more by applying more force.

Answer (score 0):

Needle valves will *always* leak eventually. Easiest repair is to get a shark connector SLIP connector. Turn off water, drain pipe. Cut out section with needle puncture with tube cutter, different valves require different sections to be cut out, marked on the slip valve. Push slip fitting in, up and over one end of newly cut pipe, pull back to meet other end Of newly cut pipe, done.

You can do the same with a repair coupling but you’ll have to bend the pipe out of the way to get it in and bend it back and then solder. Not hard, but the “non solder” solution is easier.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Do note that you've answered a 7 year old question and didn't add anything that any of the existing answers haven't already suggested. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] (especially on answering) to see how this Question & Answer format differs from most other "general discussion" formats out there.