# Leaking saddle valve

Tags: plumbing, water, leak, plumbing-fixture, saddle-valve

There is a joint of some sort leaking in one of our cold water lines running above the drop ceiling in the basement. Does anyone know what this joint is called, or why it might be leaking? It's leaking from the opening (looks like you could attach a narrow water line to it), and tightening the nut below it didn't seem to help (though I didn't tighten too much for fear of damaging it).

**Update**: it looks like it's a saddle valve, though the handle is missing. Not sure what to make of that.

[image: leaking joint]

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32345/how-do-i-fix-a-leak-at-a-decommissioned-saddle-valve , which has a bit more info on how to eliminate that, in case it's helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. At the time I posted, I didn't know it was called a saddle valve, so I wasn't having much luck with generic "leaking pipe joint" searches.

Comment: If you just want to stop the leak, and have no need to use the valve, remove the existing unit and install a similarly-shaped pipe clamp with a small piece of rubber gasket material behind it.  (FWIW, I've had a similar unit installed in this house for about 35 years, and have had no trouble with it.  Of course, it's rarely operated and the exit tube is always attached.)

Comment: @JeremiahOrr: Yes, duplicates are expected for that reason. I added the link since that one has more info, and someone with more points than me can close it as a duplicate. Tester101 is right btw, it's safest to eliminate that. Especially since you have a drop ceiling making it not visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were some good suggestions to replace/remove the saddle valve, and I'll likely do that eventually. For now, though, I was able to cap it off with a 1/4" compression cap, similar to the one pictured below.

[image: compression cap]

Comment: Good work... I thought of that, but figured if you were going to the store then the thing to get would be a coupling (if you're no longer using the valve).

Comment: Beware of it eventually leaking through the valve stem as the packing gets older.

Comment: picture of final result please?

Answer (score 10):

Turn the water off, and remove it. Those things are rubbish, and always leak eventually.

If you need a valve there, cut out the damaged section of pipe, and install a proper tee and valve. If you don't need it, cut out the damaged section of pipe and install a coupling.

If you're not an expert solderer, They make push-fit fittings (SharkBite® is the well known brand) that are easy to work with. These fittings are more expensive than typical fittings, but ease of use and not having to buy soldering supplies might make them comparable.

Answer (score 6):

It's a self-piercing saddle valve like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB76LXrYKsU . If you're familiar with electronics, it works a lot like the so-called "vampire tap" for coax cable.

Regardless, it's a quick and easy solution in the short-term, but they tend not to last. Because they are cheap, they tend to fail easily, and because they are easy, they tend to be used in situations where they aren't really appropriate.

If this valve is actually supplying water to something, it'd be worth replacing this valve with a true T-connection and a "real" valve.
If it's NOT supplying water to something, it'd be a good idea to remove it and patch the gap with a proper coupling.
There's also the possibility that you could remove it and just patch the hole that it leaves behind, but that might not last very long either.

If you're up for it, soldering copper pipe is not at all beyond the adventurous homeowner, but it is a pretty advanced task, so you're not going to find a kit or instructions at Lowe's. You'll have to learn about soldering (a non-trivial task), and get the proper equipment (a propane torch, flux, and solder).

I just spent two years adding insulation and replacing the siding on my house by myself, and if I was in your shoes, I'd hire a plumber ;-)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

It's a self tapping valve, usually to provide water to a fridge.
You can either replace it or eliminate it (use a coupling instead).

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two solutions:

**1. Remove the saddle valve and replace with a coupling**
You need to do this if it is leaking from the rubber flashing around the pipe.

**2. Cap the Valve**

You can unscrew the valve stem retaining nut and cap the top and side of the valve with compression nuts as described above.  You can do this if, for instance, the valve stem is leaking (leak out of the 'top'), or the valve is not fully closing/seating (leak out of the 'side')

Answer (score 2):

If you remove that, water is going to spray everywhere.  You might be able to find a cap to screw onto it at the local hardware store.

If it's at the end of the pipe you can easily fix it by:

1. Turning off the water
2. Purchase a pipe cutter (sort of looks like the letter C) and costs about $16.00 USD
3. Purchase a 3/4" or 1/2" Shark bite connector.  Around $5.00 USD
4. Cut the pipe.  (It's easy with the C shaped cutter.)
5. Slide the shark-bite connector on the end.  It clicks into place.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the UK one would normally use a compression repair coupler to repair a copper water pipe. Normally because it's burst but it would work just as well after removing that (presumablly) redundant and leaky valve.

The repair coupler is longer than a normal coupler and only one end has a depth stop which makes it easy to slide onto a gap in existing pipework. After sliding it into place you tighten the nuts to compress the olives and make a seal.

http://www.screwfix.com/p/compression-repair-fitting-15-x-100mm/85529

I don't know if similar products are available in other countries.